# DB2 performance lack in subselect

Tags: db2, db2-luw

In my subselect, I select for a view, which takes 30% longer time
then to copy the content of the view into this query.
Is their any solution to handle this with a view.

```
select *
    from abc
    where id = 1
    and ref_id in 
    (select ref
    from view_vc
    )
```

Comment: Provide enough information, so that someone can understand the question. Which Db2 version and platform? What table structures? What queries are you comparing? Have you looked into the query plans? Typically, Db2 tries to avoid any copying of data unless instructed

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: It is DB2 LUW, version 11.5.
How can I enforce in a query that data should be copied?